# Elements get smaller in a CSS grid layout

Tags: html, css

I'm making a Website with a CSS grid layout, but there is a problem with elements not having the correct height.

So I basically have this:

```
<div id="gridcontainer">
  <div id="grid1" class="grids">
    <div class="element1"></div>
    <div class="element2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="grid2" class="grids">
    <div class="element1"></div>
    <div class="element2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="grid3" class="grids">
    <div class="element1"></div>
    <div class="element2"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="grid4" class="grids">
    <div class="element1"></div>
    <div class="element2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this:

```
#gridcontainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.grids {
  position: absolute;
  display: grid;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.element1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
  height: 100%;
}

.element2 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
  height: 100%;
}

#grid1 {
  grid-row: 1;
}

#grid2 {
  grid-row: 2;
}

/* ... */
```

My problem is that the grids get smaller and won't stick to the 25% height of the row template. `#grid1` is still at 25% height, `#grid4` is around 10%… Is there any way to fix this?

[This is an image of what the grid looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHsky.png)

Comment: Make sure to close all your `div`s properly.

Comment: Oh sorry, just some typos for the issue

Comment: `grid-template-columns` is the correct css property and your container should have an height set because each child is relying on a % relative to its parent to define its height and there's no content anywhere to give any height to any element. So maybe just setting the `height` of the main container will bring you somewhere. Then if you show the div borders you'll see something `div{border: solid 1px;}`

Comment: The code I provided is really shortened, im going to edit it, to replicate it to the exact original

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found the solution. There was a faulty `position: absolute` in the `.grids` class (idk when I added it), which caused the problem. After removing it, it works.

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer so that other users will easily be able to see what the problem was.

Comment: I can accept my own answer in 2 days, but I will, when possible